# IPv6 does not work over bridge

Tags: networking, 14.04, virtualization, network-bridge, ipv6

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 server a week ago. I use it as a virtual machine host (tasksel installed). meaning am running it with kvm + libvirt.

I have set up the same bridge I had in 13.10.

```
auto p4p1
iface p4p1 inet manual
    up ifconfig $IFACE up
    down ifconfig $IFACE down

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 46.182.xxx.xxx
    netmask 255.255.255.240
    gateway 46.182.xxx.xxx
    dns-nameservers 46.182.xxx.xxx 46.182.xxx.xxx
    bridge_ports p4p1
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_maxwait 0

iface br0 inet6 auto
```

Against br0 I connect my virtual machines with `<source bridge='br0'/>` defined in libvirt.

My virtual machines get Router Advertisement messages without problem. All virtual machines get IPv6 addresses.

My problem is that IPv6 does not work over the bridge. But it does work when I turn on tcpdump against br0 for troubleshooting. I have tried setting the interface manually into promiscous mode but that does not make it work, `ifconfig br0 promisc`.

Why I have the IPv4 addresses on the bridge? I do not know, old habit, never question it. IPv6 does not work on the virtual machine host but the host get IPv6 address by RA, just like the virtual machines.

Comment: If the VMs get IPv6 addresses that means there are IPv6 packets going over the bridge from the network to the VM. Otherwise the VMs wouldn't see the router advertisements. Is there any firewalling or filtering on the bridge?

Comment: This is standard ubuntu 14.04 server that I have installed and then added "virtual machine host" with tasksel. There is no firewall activated that I know of. iptables -L is clean.

Comment: IPv6 uses ip6tables. Can you check that one as well?

Comment: ip6tables -L is clean

Comment: Hmmm. Weird. All I can think of right now is to run tcpdump/wireshark/tshark on the interfaces to see where the packets get stuck.

Comment: it does work when I turn on tcpdump against br0 for troubleshooting. When I quit tcpdump, IPv6 stops working.

Comment: Use `-p` so that `tcpdump` won't enter promiscuous mode. Though [I think you should turn on STP](http://serverfault.com/q/528449/126632).

Comment: When using tcpdump with -p I can now see incoming IMCPv6 RA messages, nothing outgoing. I also enabled STP but no joy. This means IPv6 starts to work when I turn on promiscous mode and does not work when promiscous mode ís off.

Answer (score 11):

Every IPv6 address, even link-local ones, automatically subscribe to a multicast group based on its last 24 bits. If multicast snooping is enabled, the bridge filters out (almost) all multicast traffic by default. When an IPv6 address is assigned to an interface, the system must inform the network that this interface is interested in that particular multicast group and must be excluded by the filter. The following is a good introductory video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1JMdjnn0ao

Multicast snooping is there to prevent flooding the network with multicast packets that most systems aren't interested. You can disable multicast snooping in small deployments without noticing any big difference. But this may have significant performance impact on larger deployments.

You can disable snooping with:

```
echo -n 0 > /sys/class/net/<brif>/bridge/multicast_snooping
```

If you want to protect your VMs from unwanted traffic and unnecessary packet processing, you can leave snooping enabled but also enable a multicast Querier on the network. A Querier will periodically broadcast query packets and update snooping filters on switches and bridges. It is possible to enable a Querier on your system with:

```
echo -n 1 > /sys/class/net/<brif>/bridge/multicast_querier
```

If you have snooping enabled, you must also have a querier on the network.

There's no need to enable STP. It's probably safer to turn it off, unless you know that you're bridging segments that result in circular paths. It's also irrelevant if you have SLAAC enabled (ie `autoconf=1`, `accept_ra=1`). Enabling PROMISC mode on the bridge implicitly disables snooping.

Here's a nice summary of the modern [challenges of IPv6 Neighbor Discovery (ND) and Multicast Listener Discovery (MLD)](http://blog.ipspace.net/2014/09/ipv6-neighbor-discovery-nd-and.html).

Answer (score 4):

have you enabled IPv6 on the interface at all? if the bridge device is br0, then do this:

```
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.br0.disable_ipv6=0
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.br0.autoconf=1
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.br0.accept_ra=1
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.br0.accept_ra_defrtr=1
```

Comment: sysctl net.ipv6.conf.br0.accept_ra=1 is 0 as default. I can not test this because I switched to separated physical interface on the server and then it started to work. So I can not troubleshoot this anymore. Meaning, I have sysctl net.ipv6.conf.br0.accept_ra=0 and it still works for my vhosts.

Comment: This is the right answer.

Comment: In my case I need to set /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/br0/accept_ra to be 2. Because otherwise Linux kernel won't process the ra. See function ipv6_accept_ra() in linux kernel, which will decide if ra should be accepted for an interface. If the interface can forward packets, then accept_ra needs to be 2 for linux kernel to configure SLAAC on it.

Answer (score 0):

The only obvious problem I see with your configuration is:

```
    bridge_stp off
```

For various reasons [STP needs to be enabled](https://serverfault.com/a/528453/126632) on libvirt bridges.

Change the configuration to:

```
    bridge_stp on
```

You can also activate it immediately without restarting the network:

```
$ sudo brctl stp br0 on
```